# Identification of Power Cable Type

Tags: power, cables

I've searched and can't seem to figure out what power cord I need to get for this device. On the back it says:

Power: Input --> 100-240V, 50/60Hz   Output --> 12V-2A 5V-3.5A

[image: Power Cord Receiver]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Choosing power supply, how to get the voltage and current ratings?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34745/choosing-power-supply-how-to-get-the-voltage-and-current-ratings)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [Mini-DIN6 connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector).

As for the proper voltage being supplied through it, you'll need to look around online. Should be easy once you know the connector type.

Comment: The voltage is easy, he already knows it. It's the pinout that's the problem. Ten bucks says it's a thin-client or hard drive enclosure (I have both with the same type of connector and power requirements).

Answer (score 1):

While that is a standard [Mini-DIN6 connector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini-DIN_connector), there isn't a standard wiring pattern that specifies which pin is what. You will either need to order a power cord from the manufacturer, or open up the device and see if you can figure out what is what. If you're lucky, something is marked on the inside to show which pin is what.

Comment: It have a standard and can order one too! Look the first answer.

Comment: @Butzke the connector is standard. however, there is not a standard wiring configuration associated with that connector.

Comment: @longneck then you should update your answer with that clarification. For what it's worth, I have Iomega external Harddrives and Wyse thinclients with that connecter + power needs.